# ruby rpartition deletes a character from original string

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"Max Vázquez Evans".rpartition(/\s+/)
=> ["Max Vázquez ", " ", "vans"]
```

As you can see, rpartition method is deleting "E". Can someone help?

I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result (v2.3). Must you use that last name?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I can reproduce it on 2.0.0

Comment: I cannot replicate, but suspect problems with character encoding. Could you show 1) What happens when you do `"Max Vazquez Trump".rpartition(/\s+/)` (i.e. without accent). 2) What you get from `"Max Vázquez Trump".encoding`

Comment: Perhaps, you can use `"Max Vázquez Trump".split(/(\s+)(?=\S*\z)/)` to work around it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes I did. As @neil-slater said, it does indeed seem to be an issue with character encoding. `"Max Vázquez Trump".encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_1).rpartition(/\s+/)` works perfectly. I'll let @neil-slater answer the question.

Comment: @max_: "Max Vázquez Trump".encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_1).rpartition(/\s+/) yields me  ["Max V\xE1zquez", " ", "Trump"]. Which is wrong.

Comment: @riship89 It's not wrong, but it doesn't answer your question. In order to make `rpartition` on 1.9.3 work with foreign characters is to convert the string to ISO-8859-1 and then convert it back to UTF-8 when you read it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: changed the last name

Comment: Works fine on Ruby 2.3.0. Ruby 1.9.3 handled encoding differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @neil-slater said, the reason why this is occurring is because of the way encoding is handled prior to 2.3.0.

In order to ensure that this works on versions earlier than 2.3.0, you can reduce the foreign-characters to their iso character codes, and then revert to the original encoding afterwards.

```
x = "Max Vázquez Trump".encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_1).rpartition(/\s+/)
# => ["Max V\xE1zquez", " ", "Trump"]
y = x.map do |a| a.encode("utf-8") end
#  => ["Max Vázquez", " ", "Trump"]
```